# Closing Notification With Swipe Not Working

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to close a notification with the swipe but it just won't close. I have tried setting the correct flags as well as setting the OnGoing to false but I have no luck.

This is the code I have:

```
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContent(remoteViews)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .build();

            notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

       // Additional code

        Intent playpause = new Intent();
        playpause.setAction("com.eciflow.project.pause");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, playpause, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Intent stop = new Intent();
        stop.setAction("com.eciflow.project.stop");

        PendingIntent stopI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, stop, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.playpause, R.drawable.pauseradio);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.stop, R.drawable.stopradio);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.playpause, pi);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.stop, stopI);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Playing");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, param2);
        remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.title, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.text, getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));


        startForeground(250, notification);
```

I am playing music in the background from a stream...

Any ideas why this is happening? If there are other alternatives I am open to changing the structure as well.

Thanks!

Comment: try to use "NotificationCompat" instead of "Notification".

Answer (score 0):

Add this code while setting flag:
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Comment: where would I add this? If I added in the code above, the phone won't stop vibrating. I am guessing that is not the correct place to put it.

Comment: Add it replacing the below code:                notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;